# Username cannot be of email format, since user pool is configured for email

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When I try sign up an user in AWS Cognito this error is returned in response.:

[image]

But, in my config the email field is an alias.:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By that error message, it looks like it's failing because you have email as an alias but have also set given it as your username. I think to get around this, you could either use some temporary, throw away username at first or un-check it as an alias and just use it as both username and an attribute. The former gives you more flexibility to updating it, but that's ultimately up to your application's needs.